# Read the value from a virtual memory address in a program every frame

Tags: linux, memory, c

I've been trying to write a program in C that reads the value of a virtual memory address in a game so I can tell when it's loading. This is pretty easy to do on Windows but I can't seem to find much info on doing it in Linux.

All of the solutions I've tried either don't work or they cause the game to freeze. I need a solution that can read this address every frame or as close as possible to that.

What way could I go about doing this?

I've tried using ptrace and reading from /proc/mem so far. Using ptrace causes the program to freeze and so far I haven't gotten reading from /proc/mem to work at all.

EDIT: I've decided to try and use the process_vm_readv syscall and the game no longer freezes but for some reason it outputs the number 3640913997.

Here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
 
struct StockPid
{
    pid_t pid;
    char buff[512];
    FILE *pid_pipe;
} stockthepid;
 
void Func_StockPid(const char *processtarget)
{
    stockthepid.pid_pipe = popen(processtarget, "r");
    fgets(stockthepid.buff, 512, stockthepid.pid_pipe);
    stockthepid.pid = strtoul(stockthepid.buff, NULL, 10);
 
    if (stockthepid.pid == 0)
    {
        printf("Jet Set Radio isn't running. \n");
        pclose(stockthepid.pid_pipe);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Jet Set Radio is running - PID NUMBER -> {%d} \n", stockthepid.pid);
        pclose(stockthepid.pid_pipe);
    }
}
 
void ReadProcessMemory(int pid) {
 
    struct iovec in;
    in.iov_base= (void *) 0x58FAAC;
    in.iov_len = 4;

    uint32_t foo;

    struct iovec out;
    out.iov_base = &foo;
    out.iov_len = sizeof(foo);

    do {
        ssize_t nread = process_vm_readv(stockthepid.pid, &out, 1, &in, 1, 0);
        if(nread == -1) {
            printf("error %s");
        } else if(nread != in.iov_len) {
            printf("error: short read of %li bytes", (ssize_t)nread);
        }
        std::cout << foo << std::endl;
    } while(true);
}
 
 
 
int main()
{
    Func_StockPid("pidof -s jetsetradio.exe");
    ReadProcessMemory(stockthepid.pid);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit again :) : Changing `in.iov_len` to 2 gives me a number that I'd expect (61517) but that number doesn't ever change.

Comment: Would you mind listing the approaches you’ve already tried? That would reduce the risk of people wasting your time by suggesting solutions that won’t work.

Comment: @StephenKitt I've tried using ptrace and reading from /proc/mem so far. Using ptrace causes the program to freeze and so far I haven't gotten reading from /proc/mem to work at all.

Comment: instead of a full game, maybe try this with a dummy program (e.g., something that just counts up a counter every 1s, so you can test whether it works). Also note that Linux has [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) which would usually mitigate exactly the attack you're driving against the game.